# Cos/Sin Simplification

Tags: trigonometry

I've written 
$$\sqrt{\left(1-0.5\cos(\omega)\right)^2+\left(0.5\sin(\omega)\right)^2}$$

and needs to simplify this. I know that I should be able to rewrite it to $1.25 - \cos(\omega)$ but I really don't know how. My first approach was to find some kind of formula for using directly, that failed. My second approach was to expand and convert all terms to cos terms. It gives me 
$$\sqrt{1 - \cos(\omega) +0.25\cos^2(\omega) -  \frac{0.25}{\cos^2(\omega)}}$$

I doubt that this is the correct approach.

Comment: $$(a-b\cos A)^2+(b\sin A)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos A$$

Comment: The inside part of the radical goes to what you are saying but that is not the final answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you converted the $\sin$ in $\cos$ but it looks wrong. You can use

$$0.25\cos^2(x)+0.25\sin^2(x)=0.25(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))=0.25$$

So your end result is $\sqrt{1.25-\cos(x)}$